# While inserting uniqid() in to table id is not inserting in correct way

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier, codeigniter-3

While inserting uniqid() in my table using codeigniter insertion, that uniqid() is not insewrting in correct way like last inserted id is insertng in middle in middle of the data so, when I try to retrieve uniqid using MAX(ID) i am getting duplicate id..

so can any one help to resolve the issue how to overcome this and how to insert the id in sequence

Comment: Of course MAX(ID) isn't unique, since it's the highest ID in your table. Try MAX(ID) + 1.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has build in support for generating incrementing IDs for columns. Try adding an `IDENTITY` column to your table. Note that you can't add an `IDENTITY` constraint to an existing column.

You have 2 options:

1. Create a new table with identity & drop the existing table
2. Create a new column with identity & drop the existing column

Read more here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04d69ee6-d4f5-4f8f-a115-d89f7bcbc032/how-to-alter-column-to-identity11?forum=transactsql